# How to add textbox dynamically within the div tag by looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add data coming from the success function in the ajax call( var data) into text boxes dynamically like code given below. I need to add each text box within the div tag. Tell me the way of adding each text box within the div tag in side the for loop.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'GRNgetItem.php',
    data: postForm1,
    //dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
       var container = document.getElementById('item');
       // var container = document.getElementById('item_Name');
       var dd = data;
       var data = (typeof dd) == 'string' ? eval('(' + dd + ')') : dd;
       for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var txtItemId = document.createElement('input');
          txtItemId.type = 'text';
          txtItemId.id = 'ItemId_' + i; // Set id based on "i" value
          txtItemId.name='ItemId[]';
          txtItemId.class='col-md-2';
          txtItemId.value=data[i].ItemId;
          container.appendChild(txtItemId);        
          var txtItemName = document.createElement('input');
          txtItemName.type = 'text';
          txtItemName.id = 'ItemName_' + i; // Set id based on "i" value
          txtItemId.name='ItemName[]';
          txtItemName.class='col-md-2';
          txtItemName.value=data[i].ItemName;
          container.appendChild(txtItemName);    
          var txtItemQty = document.createElement('input');
          txtItemQty.type = 'text';
          txtItemQty.id = 'ItemQty_' + i; // Set id based on "i" value
          txtItemId.name='ItemQty[]';
          txtItemQty.class='col-md-2';
          txtItemQty.value=data[i].Qty;
          container.appendChild(txtItemQty);
          var txtItemRPrice= document.createElement('input');
          txtItemRPrice.type = 'text';
          txtItemRPrice.id = 'ItemPrice_' + i; // Set id based on "i" value
          txtItemId.name='ItemPrice[]';
          txtItemRPrice.class='col-md-2';
          txtItemRPrice.value="";
          container.appendChild(txtItemRPrice);  
       }    
    }
});
```

Comment: Use `JSON.parse` to get the data from the request, *never* `eval()`. Aside from that, your current JS code seems to be doing what you require already is there an issue with it? Note that you can make the code much more succinct by using jQuery to create the elements, but that won't affect it's logic.

Comment: That is not the issue data is coming into the text box correctly. I want to add each text box into div tags seperatly

Comment: Why don't you just create a div, just like you have created your inputs? So you create a div for each of your inputs and then append the input to that div?

Comment: How to append the textbox inside the div?

Comment: It may not be *the* issue, but it is certainly a *big issue* you need to fix

Comment: @Reality-Torrent I get the feeling this is a copy/paste from another question but the OP doesn't fully understand it. Hence `txtItemRPrice.value="";` the default value is empty so not sure why it would need to be defined/set.

Comment: I want to define  empty text box for the price for each item.

Comment: "*How to append the textbox inside the div?*" - How are you appending your textboxes to `container`?

Comment: I already appended text box to container. Inside the container I want several div tags for each text box.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this Javascript

```
var container = document.getElementById('item');
var div = document.createElement('div');
var txtItemId = document.createElement('input');
txtItemId.type = 'text';
txtItemId.id = 'ItemId_' ; 
txtItemId.name='ItemId[]';
txtItemId.class='col-md-2';
txtItemId.value=1;
div.appendChild(txtItemId);

console.log(container.appendChild(div))
```

This will show you `textbox` inside the `DIV` tag. Change other script accordingly